# How can I copy an Excel sheet into a workbook whose windows are not visible?

Tags: excel, vba

```
source.Sheets(RevisionHistory).Copy before:=target.Sheets(1)
```

This does not work when all the windows for the 'target' workbook are not visible. When Visible=True for them, then it works.

The easy answer is just to make them visible. But, they are being worked on and it a problem for the user to see all that activity.

Comment: If your using VBA, can't you just set visibility to true before you copy and then set it back to false afterwards?

Comment: Oh my god, Rich B, stop making unnecessary edits! There is no reason to delete words that make the question more cordial and friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before making the sheet temporarily visible. Remember to set it back to `True` again :-)

Comment: Excellent! I was unaware of this property. And, it goes back to Excel 2003 and before! Thanks a bunch Gary.

Warning to other developers: making a workbook's windows not visible gets remembered for the file. Opening it again shows no tabs or data. ...Rick